# lock(variable) - conflicting explanation of the variable

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

[The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) don't explain it. They only say what should be locked on and what not.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193385/939213)  it seems like the same object should be used by all threads for the lock to work. While from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251399/939213)  it seems that that is exactly what should be avoided to prevent deadlock.

Keep in mind that I might be misunderstanding this whole matter of lock, because I just [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373936/block-a-concurrent-collection-such-as-a-concurrentbag-or-blockingcollection) about how to "lock" a **variable** and got *what seems to me* not to achieve that at all (except locking **code**).

Comment: Don't explain *what*? "The lock keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for *a given object*, executing a statement, and then releasing the lock." - seems pretty clear. Note the use of *object*, not *variable*, in the documentation.

Comment: `lock for a given object` - That.

Comment: What isn't clear about that? A `lock` establishes mutual exclusion (when applied against the *same object*) between threads.

Comment: The docs that you linked to explain quite a lot more than what should and should not be locked on, including what the statement does, which is what you're asking.

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to lock? Threading can be complex. It's hard to give you an answer other than read the answers provided in those threads. IMO- no you shouldn't lock(this){...} and then in other example the object should be as a field and not a variable again as described in the answers on that thread. It will be a lot easier to help you lock correctly with example code

Comment: Yes, locking solves race-conditions and introduces the risk of deadlock. Win some, lose some. You'll have to use them in exactly the right way, that's why this is not a good question. Details matter.

Comment: "I just asked a question about how to "lock" a variable" - You don't lock *an* object, you lock *on* an object. The code inside the lock statement is the *thing* that gets locked. I think that's the crux of your confusion. There seems to be a disconnect between your expectations and what happens. What do you expect to happen when you lock on an object?

Comment: @dcastro Thanks. "confusion" - Yes. Exactly. That's what I thought StackOverflow was about - asking questions when one doesn't understand something. Apparently that's not the case anymore. (I'm not referring to you. Just venting. :)

Comment: Downvotes do not have to be explained. But to give you an idea: a good question can stand on its own and is much more specific and/or detailed. It could/should have been an edit to your previous question.

Comment: @ispiro One should be *precise* about questions; providing an example test-case usually helps bring about this clarity; as would extracting specific excerpts and the [read] implications of such. Otherwise, others can't tell *what* the question is really about - as in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a lock as a "talking stick" that is used in some meetings.  Whoever is holding the stick can talk. Anyone that wants to talk must wait until the speaker relinquishes the stick.

When a piece of code acquires a lock on an object, any other piece of code that requests a lock *on that same object* must wait until the original code releases the lock.

So which object should you lock?  It depends greatly on the context.  The rule of thumb is you lock an object that *anyone else who could affect the code block* can lock as well.  If you're updating a collection, then you can `ICollection.SyncRoot` as an example.

**EDIT by OP** (Hopefully correct)**:**
"Anyone that wants to talk"  - As the speaker "of that stick". (Anyone can just talk.)
As for the second link in the question - it's referring to a problem of one lock waiting for a second, while the second is waiting for the first.

Comment: Thanks. But, then, what about the second answer linked in my question that _seems_ (yes, I know, _seems_) to say the opposite?

Comment: OK I misstated a bit in my answer.  I'll revise it.

Comment: I just edited your answer (and accepted it.) I hope that's OK. If not - please rollback. Thanks again.

Comment: Your edit just explains the purpose of the talking stick, which is fine.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

`lock` should be used around any shared resource. By "shared resource" I mean anything that is accessed by more than one thread.

All a lock does is:

1. Incoming thread wants access to a piece of code, encounters lock
2. Lock is empty, thread is allowed in
3. Thread gets switched out
4. Another thread wants access to the same code (or code locked on the same variable), encounters lock
5. Variable is already locked, thread has to wait
6. Original thread is switched back in, exits locked code
7. Second thread is switched back in, executes the locked code

If it is possible to have threads in a lock and waiting on *another* lock at the same time, that then waits on the first lock, you have a gridlock condition. Typically you don't "nest" your locks to avoid this problem. Also, for performance if nothing else, you rarely lock on the same variable as another unless you actually have both pieces relying on the code not executing concurrently (probably a bad design if it is so :) )

Comment: Thanks. I accepted another answer because it made it clearer for me. But your answer helped as well. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Locking something is intended to protect a piece of **shared memory**.  So, you have to use the same `SyncRoot` for a specific element that you are protecting...  However, say you have 3 objects that need to be protected, and they are in no way related:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
```

Then there is NO reason to use the same `SyncRoot` for all 3 of them.  In fact, if they are truly separate, it would be inefficient.